# What is this data table ={TABLE(,D3)} doing?

Tags: excel, datatable

I received an Excel file with a data table that is 6 columns by 10 rows and each cell contains a value. The first cell contains ={TABLE(,D3)}. I am trying to figure out how the values in each cell is being calculated but the data table is referencing a cell that starts with a comma (,D3).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure whether this is the right place for your question: It refers to the input cell and is part of a so-called “data table” (also not sure whether you used this exact same expression on purpose or by coincidence). Anyway, you may want to ask your favorite search engine for more ob out Excel data tables. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe you see {=TABLE(,D3)}    and not  ={TABLE(,D3)} ??